# Bottom Navigation Bar not working inside fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-bottomnav

I am trying to show a Bottom Navigation Bar with 3 items inside a fragment, and it shows correctly without errors in my code. But the thing is that when I click on one of the options, the code supposed to be run doesn't work, it doesn't even log anything on the console. 
TransporteFragment.Java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class TransporteFragment extends Fragment {


    public TransporteFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_busC1:

                    return true;
                case R.id.action_busC2:
                    BusC2Fragment busC2Fragment = new BusC2Fragment();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.espacioLineas, busC2Fragment).commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_busC3:

                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_transporte, container, false);

        BottomNavigationView navegacion = (BottomNavigationView) v.findViewById(R.id.navbartransporte);
        navegacion.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_transporte, container, false);
    }

}
```

fragment_transporte.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.gberti.smarthuesca.TransporteFragment">



    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/espacioLineas">

    </FrameLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/navbartransporte"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/navbar_transporte_items" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `onCreateView` method instead of `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_transporte, container, false);` try `return v;`

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the only issue, and I had thought that there would be no problem, but now it works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. it's working but I have one more issue. In my app, I have a navigation drawer. so from the navigation drawer, I click B fragment. then come to A fragment(bottom navigation) destroy the state. always come at first fragment of bottom navigation.